# Trouble showing that the "naive" dilaton vertex operator is not primary

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

**Context**:

On page 167 of [David Tong's string theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html), he writes that

> "a naive construction of the [dilaton's] vertex operator is not primary".

I assume that by this he means an operator such as
\begin{equation}
: \partial X^\mu \bar{\partial} X^\nu e^{ik \cdot X} :
\end{equation}
contracted with $\eta_{\mu \nu}$, which is the image of the naive dilaton state $\eta_{\mu \nu} \alpha^\mu_{-1} \tilde{\alpha}^\nu_{-1}|0;k\rangle$ under the state-operator map, with some normalization in front. I am trying to verify Tong's statement, by computing the OPE of the above expression with the energy-momentum tensor
\begin{equation}
T = -\frac{1}{\alpha^\prime} :\partial X^\rho \partial X_\rho : 
\end{equation}
and checking if a term more singular than $1/z^2$ appears. The most singular term in the OPE should come from the double cross-contractions in the OPE of
\begin{equation}
:\partial X^\rho(z) \partial X_\rho(z) : : \partial^\prime X^\mu(z^\prime) \bar{\partial}^\prime X^\nu(\bar{z}^\prime): ,
\end{equation}
where $\partial^\prime = \partial_{z^\prime}$.

**The question**:

Applying the algorithm developed in the second chapter of Polchinski volume 1 to compute the OPE of the above product leads me to
\begin{align}
:\partial X^\rho(z) \partial X_\rho(z) : : \partial^\prime X^\mu(z^\prime) \bar{\partial}^\prime X^\nu(\bar{z}^\prime):  &= \frac{{\alpha^\prime}^2}{2} \Big( \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial \partial^\prime \ln|z-z^\prime|^2 \partial \bar{\partial}^\prime \ln|z-z^\prime|^2 \Big) + \text{less singular} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{{\alpha^\prime}^2}{2} \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial^\prime \frac{1}{z-z^\prime} \bar{\partial}^\prime \frac{1}{z-z^\prime} + \text{less singular} \\[5pt]
&= - {\alpha^\prime}^2 \pi \eta^{\mu \nu} \frac{1}{(z-z^\prime)^2} \delta^{(2)}(z-z^\prime,\bar{z} - \bar{z}^\prime) + \text{less singular}.
\end{align}
All I have done here is contracting pairs of fields and replacing each contraction by $-\alpha^\prime/2 \, \eta^{\mu_1 \mu_ 2} \ln|z_{12}|^2$, and written explicitly only the double contractions. The delta function shows up because
\begin{equation}
\partial \bar{\partial} \ln|z|^2 = \bar{\partial} \frac{1}{z} = 2 \pi \delta^{(2)}(z,\bar{z}).
\end{equation}

In chapter 2 (page 45) of Polchinski's book, he writes that the OPE of any operator with the energy momentum tensor $T(z) = T_{zz}(z)$ is of the form of a Laurent series in $(z-z^\prime)$, so my result must be wrong, as it includes a delta function due to the antiholomorphic derivative in the operator. What is going on here? Including the exponential $\exp(ik \cdot X)$ does not fix it.

Comment: If you're not using the OPE inside an integral, delta functions should be dropped.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why? And do you mean that this term as a whole should be dropped?

Comment: The delta function will only be nonzero for OPEs of the form $:A(z): :B(z):$ which make no sense anyway. There is probably more that can be said about the delta function being an artefact of the formalism all along since 2pt functions need to vanish unless the operators involved have the same left and right moving scaling dimensions.